# Serialization and deserialization of json objcts

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

So I want to parse the response from server. The aim is to build unified system that will receive the response and build the object than serialize it back.

There are 4 types of response from the server:

*Type 1* : items is the array of objects with two or more key-value items;

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 456239048,
        "key1": "value_1",
        "key2": "value_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*Type 2*: Items can also have another inner object called for example city;

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 923,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test",
        "city": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "city1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Test2",
        "last_name": "Test2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And finally the last two types of response:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And the second one

```
{
  "error": {
    "error_code": 14
  }
}
```

They are the response of server's conditions and so on.

So I implemented several classes to achieve my target. 
And more time: 
 - serialization and deserialization (json1 => object=> json2; json1=json2);
 - access to object methods and values.

```
public class DataModelDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

        @Override
        public T deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonElement items=null;

            try{
                items = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new Gson().fromJson(items, type);
        }
    }
```

DataModel.java

```
    public class DataModel {
    private Response response;


    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }


}
```

Response.java

```
    public class Response<T> {
    private int count;
    private List<T> items=new ArrayList<T>();
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Items.java

```
 public class Items {
        private int id;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
     }
```

And starting with a good news - this approach helps me to achieve the first aim - covert json to object and back. Hovewer I have no access to the values of Items object; I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to com.app.Items

Yep, I think that this approach is not really good, because I faced with the problem how to determine what type of response is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your response format to something that is standard across response types.

```
{
    "success":"true",
    "responseData": {
        // your data here
    },
    "errorMessage": "only set if success == false",
    "errorData": {
        // any error data here
    }
}
```

Then you can use the same parsing logic for all types of responses while knowing ahead of time what sort of response it is based on the value of the `success` field.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot edit response format. The only idea that I have is to add to json property called type and work with it, but it's quiet hacky...

Comment: How can you not edit the response format but still add a json property to it?